# updating column value by multiplication and rounding off

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i want to multiply my db column( **".$subject_column."_theory**) value with 10/7(
my subject total is 70, and i want to convert it to 100 for finding the grade.)
also after multiplication the result must be rounded off

```
    $update_subject_statement4 = "UPDATE ".$track_table_name."

    SET `".$subject_column."` =IF(`".$subject_column."_theory`='ab',0,`".$subject_column."_theory`) WHERE
                                     evaluation_division="."'$eval_div' AND evaluation_config_id = ".$config_id." AND stream_index = ".$stream_index;   
                                    $additional_sum_update_query = $this->db->query($update_subject_statement4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$update_subject_statement4 = "UPDATE ".$track_table_name."

SET `".$subject_column."` = ROUND(IF(`".$subject_column."_theory`='ab',0,`".$subject_column."_theory`) * 7 / 10) 
WHERE
evaluation_division="."'$eval_div' 
AND evaluation_config_id = ".$config_id." 
AND stream_index = ".$stream_index;   

$additional_sum_update_query = $this->db->query($update_subject_statement4);
```

**1st:** we [multiplied](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_times) your value with **7/10**

IF(`".$subject_column."_theory`='ab',0,`".$subject_column."_theory`) *** 7 / 10**

**2nd:** we [rounded](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) it

**ROUND(** IF(`".$subject_column."_theory`='ab',0,`".$subject_column."_theory`) * 7 / 10 **)**